# Swap between getc() and getchar() within while loop condition in C

Tags: c, count, cpu-word

In writing a simple implementation of the Unix wc tool in C, I am wondering if there is some way I can write my function to choose between `getchar()` or `getc()` in the while loop condition without copy pasting the entire loop or writing a new, nearly identical function.

Basically I would like to avoid code repetition here by making the function more flexible so it can read from a file or `stdin`. Thanks!

```
void count (char *file) {
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "r");
int c;
bool in_word = false;

while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) { //want to easily swap getc() with getchar() here
    char_count++;
    if (c == '\n') {
        line_count++;
    }
    if ((c == ' ') || (c == '\t') || (c == '\n')) {
        in_word = false;
    }
    else if (in_word == false) {
        in_word = true;
        word_count++;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: you want to swap, ok. But based on which condition?

Comment: `getchar()` is the same as `fgetc(stdin)`. Why don't you just make your function use `fgetc` and take a `FILE *` as parameter. Then you can either call it with `stdin`, or with the result of a `fopen` call.

Comment: You don't need to switch between `getc()`/`getchar()`. Remember - `stdin` is a file, too! So you can use `getchar()` all the time, and when you want to read from standard input, pass `stdin` as the file handle.

Comment: fgetc sounds promising I will give that a shot. Thomas my condition is use getc() if a file is given and if not, getchar() to read from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

Under what condition do you want to swap bewtween getc() and getchar()?

If it is known at compile time, you can use a preprocessor macro like this

```
#define USE_GET_C TRUE

#if (USE_GET_C == TRUE)
  while((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) { //want to easily swap getc() with getchar() here
#else
  while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
#endif
.. remaining code below
```

If, however the condition is known only at runtime, you will need a wrapper function which will take a parameter telling you whether to use getc or getchar.

Something like this.

```
int wrapper(bool use_getc, FILE* fp);

wrapper(bool use_getc, FILE* fp)
{
    if (use_getc == TRUE)
       return(getc(fp);
    else
       return(getchar());
}
```

Comment: `== TRUE`? Why? Also, you can just use `getc(stdin)`.

Comment: Yes you can use getc(stdin) and simplify. As for putting == TRUE, it makes it easier to read. When the condition is required to be false, the macro is set false instead of commenting it out. It makes for easier maintenance,

Comment: Wait, are you talking about `#define TRUE 0`?